# How to add an option to a command only if a variable is equal to something?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'd like to add the --platform option only if the variable 'platform' is equal to 'arm64', otherwise the option should not be passed in. And I don't want to duplicate the whole command and use an if-else.

```
platform=$(uname -m)
docker run  --platform linux/arm64 \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this work-around:

```bash
platform=$(uname -m)
docker run $([[ $platform = arm64 ]] && echo "--platform linux/arm64") \
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bash script do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

platform=$(uname -m)

case "$platform" in

arm64) MOD="--platform linux/arm64" ;;
*) MOD="" ;;
esac

docker run ${MOD} IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

With command line:

```
[[ $(uname -m) = 'arm64' ]] && VAR='--platform linux/arm64' || VAR=''

docker run ${VAR} \
```

Short version:

```
[[ $(uname -m) = 'arm64' ]] && docker run --platform linux/arm64 \ || docker run \
```

I have no docker on this machine check if this works too:

```
docker run $([[ $(uname -m) = 'arm64' ]] && echo "--platform linux/arm64") \
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard bash solution for dynamic argument lists is to use an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
platform=$( uname -m )
docker_args=()
if [[ "$platform" = arm64 ]] ; then
  docker_args+=( "--platform" "linux/arm64" )
fi
docker run "${docker_args[@]}" \
```

The main benefit to this over the accepted `echo` solution is that arrays can safely preserve complex options such as those containing whitespace or globbing characters.